How to Prevent Default Sorting in Material-UI React Line Chart
<LineChart
            xAxis={[
              {
                // data: selectedTabData.xAxis,
                data: [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                // valueFormatter: (value) => Math.round(value).toString(), // This will convert to integer
                valueFormatter: (value) => value, // Return value as is (since they are now strings)
                tickMinStep: 1, // Ensures whole number steps
                tickMaxStep: 1, // Prevents intermediate decimal ticks
              },
            ]} // Replace with dynamic data if needed
            series={[
              {
                // data: selectedTabData.data,
                data: [14999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15700],
                area: true,
                baseline: "min",
                color: "rgb(197, 235, 240)",
              },
            ]}
            width={800}
            height={500}
            // yAxis={[yAxis]}
          />

I'm getting x-axis in sorted order. i want to prevent that.
Here is the docs link -> https://mui.com/x/react-charts/lines/

<LineChart
xAxis={[{
data: [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
valueFormatter: (value) => value.toString(),
tickMinStep: 1,
tickMaxStep: 1,
tickFormatter: (value) => value.toString(), // Custom tick formatter
}]}
/>
domain Setting for X-Axis -  use below
valueFormatter: (value) => value.toString(),
tickMinStep: 1,
tickMaxStep: 1,
domain: ['auto', 'auto'],  // Prevents auto sorting
}]}
